# Pivot a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I've got a table which has three columns, geoid1, geoid2 and distance.

For each record in geoid1 there are ten corresponding geoid2 records with the distance between 1 and 2.

I would like to make it a flat table with geoid1, and then the ten closest geoid2 records, by distance.

So at the moment it looks like this...

```html
GeoID1 GeoID2 Distance
100 1444 13745.4
100 1446 26757.2
100 1410 39008.3
100 1383 49338.1
100 1455 63466.3
100 1467 70949.7
100 1462 72797.3
100 1374 76524.6
100 1389 79514.5
100 1372 84596.5
42300 1388 344.317
42300 1364 441.047
42300 1387 978.223
42300 1445 6116.52
42300 1443 8577.54
42300 1413 9398.04
42300 1412 9636.99
42300 1459 11861.8
42300 1435 14330.3
42300 1419 15440.5
51401 1415 1227.49
51401 1418 3111.48
51401 1370 3208.31
51401 1434 5350.56
51401 1394 8490.85
51401 1366 8727.67
51401 1395 8727.67
51401 1396 9093.37
51401 1417 12281.4
51401 1409 13033.9
```

And I want it looking like this...

```html
GeoID1 ID2_1 ID2_2 ID2_3 ID2_4 ID2_5 ID2_6 ID2_7 ID2_8 ID2_9 ID2_10
100 1444 1446 1410 1383 1455 1467 1462 1374 1389 1372
42300 1388 1364 1387 1445 1443 1413 1412 1459 1435 1419
51401 1415 1418 1370 1434 1394 1366 1395 1396 1417 1409
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: Not really - I can't see how to get the right ordered distance geoid2 into the right column.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using a few operator like `ROW_NUMBER`, `SUM` and `CASE`. A query like this can get the exact output you wanted:

```
SELECT GeoID1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=1 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_1',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=2 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_2',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=3 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_3',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=4 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_4',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=5 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_5',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=6 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_6',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=7 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_7',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=8 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_8',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=9 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_9',
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnum=10 THEN GeoID2 END) AS 'ID2_10'
FROM
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GeoID1 ORDER BY Distance) rnum,
         GeoID1, GeoID2 FROM test2 ) A 
GROUP BY GeoID1;
```

The first assignment is to give rownumber for each of the `GeoID2` partitioned by `GeoID1` and ordered by `Distance`. Then make that as a sub-query (or base query) and perform a `SUM(CASE ..` operation over it.

Check [this fiddle out](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3eYWNRjYMgNGMeJyQ8NaZe/1).

P/S: For reference, `ROW_NUMBER()` operator only can be used in MySQL 8++ and MariaDB 10.2++ versions; whether older versions will be getting an update with this functionality or not is yet to be known.. but it seems that its extremely unlikely that older versions will get this function.